# Using EditorFor template for DisplayFor in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using an Editor Template to make an Html.EditorFor(property) in my viewModel's view.  There's a different .cshtml file containing "@Html.EditorFor(property)".

Now, depending on the value of a property of my viewModel, I need to display a DisplayFor instead.

I tried doing this by adding some conditional logic in my EditorTemplate but can't seem to access the properties of my viewModel from there (since the editor template is using @model.someOtherModel and not @viewModel).  So if I can say something like

```
// Razor
if(true)
{ EditorFor(property) }
else {DisplayFor(property)}
```

in my viewModel's view, that would work.  I just don't know how to define a "Display Template" for my object, in the same way I defined an Editor Template.

Another solution might be accessing the viewModel data from the Editor template... is this possible?

Comment: I would simply return a different View from your controller method based on the value of the boolean.  Otherwise your view is going to be littered with these `if` `else`'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Razor, you should be using something like the following syntax:

```
@if (condition) {
   @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => model.property)
} else {
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => model.property)
}
```

Are you getting a specific error you can share?

Comment: I think that's exactly his point. he can do this from View but not from JS

Comment: He didn't mention anything about Javascript.

Comment: The problem is that this particular field's EditorFor requires an editor template that I've defined, which has "Html.EditorFor" for the field (in a different cshtml).  I couldn't do this directly from the viewModel view.  So now I'm trying to do the same for this field, but DisplayFor instead.  My code snippet was meant to be razor, not JS - sorry about that

Comment: @Mik Please edit your original question to reflect what you really mean then.